# SQL JOIN 2 TABLE WITH CONDITION (DATE)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables 'barang_jadi' and 'stok_barang'. I'll show all data from table 'barang_jadi' join with 'stok_barang where stok_barang.tanggal='04-04-2015'' plus show all data from table 'barang_jadi'.

here I try, but I still don't have solution. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/306e6/1/0

[IMAGES TABLE WHEN I USING MY QUERY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NweFV.png)

Comment: Post your query and table layout here please. If sqlfiddle goes offline, your post will be lost.

Comment: I see all data from barang_jadi

Comment: You mean, You want all data from barang_jadi and those data from stok_barang whose date is 04-04-2015. do you need null data from right table?

Comment: Can you explain exact output what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
select barang_jadi.*, stok_barang.* 
from barang_jadi
left join stok_barang on barang_jadi.no=stok_barang.kode_barang where tanggal is null or tanggal = '04-04-2015'
```